# Dynamically change text values from an input box

Tags: dynamic, powerpoint

I have a text. I want to be able to change parts of this text using an input box. That will save time as I won't have to CTRL+F and change the values manually.

I created a power point file as a start. I want to make it simple so that I change the script values/attributes (e.g. background color etc) from an input box as shown below :

[image]

Is this feature possible on power point? This presentation will contain HTML/CSS scripts that the user can copy and use on a specific platform. I want the change the script values dynamically using the text box on the side.

**The reason I created the ppt file is because sites like codepen.io do not have this feature.**

*The alternative is to create a website where I will have the input box on the left and the text on the right.*

I could do that on a website using a code like :

```
<span id="myspan"></span>

document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML="VALUE";
```

but I want the VALUE to come from an input box.

It would be great if I could find a website or create something like this :
[image]

Comment: How will you identify the text to be changed?  If by color, it should be possible to do this.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg No. The color is just an example in the image.

Comment: So back to my question:  how would you identify which text is to be changed?  Can you count on the preceding text to be consistent in each case (e.g. the "background-color:#" portion) and will it always be followed by a set of three hex numbers (always the same number or characters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find a solution. I managed to create this :
[LINK](http://apolosiskos.co.uk/HTML-CSS-EDITOR/index.html)

So, there are parts in the HTML and CSS code (that are included in the blockquote) that can change through the input boxes on top. The user can enter a text and click enter. Then the value he entered in the input box will appear in the code (blockquoted). I also added the copy feature. That means that the user does not have to copy-paste the blockquoted HTML and CSS code. It can be done through a button.

PS: Snippet does not allow me to post the code because of the character limitaton